# 'getPropertyPriority' doesn't work when getting styles with 'getComputedStyle'

Tags: javascript, css

I want to get a dom style to increase the priority.

'CSSStyleDeclaration' has a 'getPropertyPriority' method and there is a problem with its return value. In the example below, when I get 'background', it returns empty, I want to get 'important'

The value obtained with 'styleSheets' is normal, but I don't want to use the loop to find the corresponding selector, I hope to give me a simple solution.

This is the document [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration/getPropertyPriority)

```js
// log is '', I want to get 'important'
console.log(window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('box')).getPropertyPriority('background'));
// log is 'important'
console.log(document.styleSheets[0].cssRules[0].style.getPropertyPriority('background'));
// log is 'important'
console.log(document.getElementById('box').style.getPropertyPriority('width'));
```

```css
#box {
  height: 100px;
  background: black !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="box" style="width: 100px !important;"></div>
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by 'I want to get a dom style to increase the priority.'?

Comment: Using `window.getComputedStyle`  returns 'A CSSStyleDeclaration object containing CSS declaration block of the element' base on [link] (https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getcomputedstyle.asp).

Comment: That's by design. The *computed* value is not the authored one and doesn't need any importance, since it will always be the only one. Like if you do `width: calc(3% + 23px)` the computed value will not be `calc(3% + 23px)`. There must be a dupe already...

Answer (score 0):

Accessing styles from `document.getElementById('box').style` or `document.styleSheets[0].cssRules[0].style` would directly give styles as is, while doing a `getComputedStyle` as the name suggests, will always give rendered styles i.e `!important` is removed, hence `getPropertyPriority` will always give `''`. I don't think there is a choice but to loop through all the styles an check.

You could check in both style sheet and the style property as you've already done:

```js
var arr = ['background', 'width', 'height'];

arr.forEach(prop => {
  //console.log(window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('box')).getPropertyPriority(prop));
  var isImportant = (document.styleSheets[0].cssRules[0].style.getPropertyPriority(prop) + document.getElementById('box').style.getPropertyPriority(prop)).length > 0;
  console.log({prop, isImportant});
});
```

```css
#box {
  height: 100px;
  background: black !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="box" style="width: 100px !important;"></div>
```

Comment: This really makes me a headache, thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The CSSStyleDeclaration object returned by getComputedStyleStyle is a bit different than the ones you'll get from say a StyleSheet or an Element's `style` property.

First this object is read-only, you can't use `setProperty` on it.

```js
const comp = getComputedStyle(test);
comp.setProperty('backgroundColor', 'green');
```

```html
<div id="test" style="height:25px;background-color:red"></div>
```

Then, at getting of its properties it will return the computed value of that property, which is not the same as the one that has been authored:

```js
const comp = getComputedStyle(test);
console.log('computed', comp.getPropertyValue('width'));

const auth = test.style;
console.log('from style', auth.getPropertyValue('width'));
```

```html
<div id="test" style="width:calc(3% + 25px)"></div>
```

And since this CSSStyleDeclaration dictionary only holds the *computed* properties, there is no need for any importance, since these properties will always be alone, and hence, `getPropertyPriority` will always return the empty string.

To retrieve the original rule that did set this property is often impossible, it could very well come from a cross-domain StyleSheet that you can't read from. And even the [incoming CSSTypedOM](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-typed-om-1/) which does give us a mean to retrieve the authored units and values doesn't expose the property importance.

Comment: Then I want to get a certain style of a dom is '!important', is there any other way?

Comment: As I said, retrieving the original rule that is currently applied is often impossible. The only way is to walk over all the rules and then check if they match your element, then order them by importance and pick the higher one (with all the rules of `#foo bar` is higher than `.baz > bar` and with things impossible to catch from js like `:visited ~ bar`)... Personally, I'd reconsider the need for this.